# Отслеживание закрытия программы winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

Нужно, чтобы после нажатия кнопки "закрыть" , программа выполняла код. Я находил решение этой задачи

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
      e.Cancel = true;
      int i = 0;
      while(i < 10)
      {

          Form1 msf = new Form1();
          msf.Show();

      }
}
```

Но данный код не работает. Как исправить **этот** код что бы он заработал ?

Comment: Вы добавили подписчик на событие? Или что вы с этим кодом вообще сделали?

Comment: @Андрей как добавить подписчик на событие закрытия программы?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы метод срабатывал при закрытии формы мало просто его написать, необходимо установить его в качестве подписчика на событие `FormClosing` вашей формы.

Это можно сделать несколькими способами, например, можно находясь в дизайнере выделить форму и перейти в окно Properties, в нем открыть события (иконка с молнией) и установить для нужного события метод:

[image: 1]

Другой способ - подписаться в коде конструктора формы, для этого перейдите в окно с кодом формы и добавьте строчку в конструкторе (обязательно после `InitializeComponent`!):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В принципе первый способ генерирует такую же строчку, просто он помещает ее в автогенерируемый файл Form1.Designer.cs в метод `InitializeComponent`

Answer (score 1):

Выберете в событиях формы событие FormClosing. Активируйте его двойным щелчком ЛКМ. И затем поместите в сгенерированный метод свой код.